# Is it correct to write $\Bbb E[X]$ or $\Bbb E_{\theta}[X]$?

Tags: expected-value, notation, sufficient-statistics

Suppose that we observe the discrete random variable $ X = (X_1, \dotsc , X_n)$ with state space
S, whose distribution we do not know but we are assuming that its joint p.m.f. belongs
to a known family $\{f_θ : θ ∈ Θ\}$. We derive a sufficient statistic $T(X)$.

Is it correct to write $\Bbb E[X]$? If not, why? Would it be more correct to write $\Bbb E_{\theta}[X]$?

Comment: Anything that is clear within your writing context would be "correct."  It comes down to whether you need explicitly to remind your readers that you are considering a particular $\theta.$

Comment: @whuber $\Bbb E[X]$ may not exist, though, no? Since the only thing we know about it is that it is dependent on $\theta$? We cannot find the value of $x$ without $\theta$? As the distribution is completely unknown?

Comment: It is a matter of notations, not of existence.